# how does drop statement works behind the scene ?

Tags: sas

```
data _null_ ;
set sashelp.cars ;

markup=invoice+msrp;

drop invoice msrp ;

run;
```

in compilation phase of data step 
PDV is intialized according to all the sas variables that are there in dataset 
then one more column is added in PDV 
but then in drop statements it drops two columns namely(invoice , msrp) from PDV 
then how come in execution phase it calculates value of markup variable which uses values of columns it has dropped already ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `drop` statement affects what variables are written out to any datasets produced by it, marking those variables to not be written out (similarly, `keep` affects in the opposite way - marking only those variables listed to be written out, and not the remaining variables).  Neither operation has any effect on the contents of the PDV during operation; it only affects what is sent to the resultant dataset(s).

There are quite a few other variables that are available during data step execution but are not written out.  Use `put _all_;` to see them.  Among others are `_N_`, the `first.` and `last.` variables produced by the `by` statement, temporary array variables, error checking variables, and more.

Comment: what about when i create new column and assign values to it , it is written out only in datasets produced  ? and pdv is not altered ?

Comment: It would be in the PDV as well.  The PDV is the temporary in-memory space allocated to process the data step; it does not relate directly to any one dataset either incoming or outgoing.

Comment: I recommend [this paper](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings12/255-2012.pdf) as a good read about the PDV.